# Xcode AR Reference Image is too similar

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, image, augmented-reality

I have an augmented reality app that plays a video on top of images and it was working very well, but as soon as I neared 50+ images, I started getting an error on some of the images, "AR reference image 'x' is too similar to 'y'." I am panicking because I need this done quickly and this error appears at random for no apart reason. In the linked picture, the reference images are clearly not similar in any way and when I even change the name of one of the pictures, it resolves itself at first until more issues of the same error come up on different reference images. If anyone has any theories or questions, please post them here! Thank you so much to anyone who can shine some light on this issue!

Image of AR Reference Image folder with error on pictures:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxv8r.jpg

**Update:** changed every image to be number 1-39 and the same images that in the last picture had errors still had errors so it must be something related to the pictures themselves. Still confused how though. Tried deleting every reference image and reuploaded exact same images and after giving each it's physical dimensions, same error popped up for 2 images still.

Is it possible to upload this update to Apple with this error and them allow it to go through? I did a test upload to my device and tested all images with errors and they all work as intended. I currently have no solution to a problem that seems very superficial. Thanks again!

Comment: You're gonna need to show some code, I think — though I'm not an AR person, nor a Swift coder.

Comment: I don't think it's a code issue. It totally could be but I doubt it bc the errors only appear on each image in a weird pattern. If there are 3 images in a row(sorted alphabetically), the first one will be fine(no errors), the second will have an error saying it is too similar to the first one, then the third will also have an error saying it too is too similar to the first. Even if I delete the first image, new errors of the same type and pattern will pop up seemingly out of nowhere that weren't listed before as well as following the same pattern of picking random images to have a problem with

Answer (score 0):

ARReference image is created from these images and even so your human eyes sees fully different images, after parsing, it might be that the detected structure is too similar (because it is not looking for exact pixel images rather characteristics of given image). This is why your problem appears after increased number of images (bigger chance of similar characteristics). So your best bet might be to use less images or if not possible, change images until all warning disappear.

If you don't use these images at the same time (Same AR session), like maybe you have some kind of selection in your application, you can try that you use a simple assets catalog for the images and loading these reference images from code. I use this method because our application downloads simple images for markers and I create the reference image programatically.

```
private func startTracking(WithMarkerImage marker: UIImage) {
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
    
    var orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation!
    
    switch marker.imageOrientation {
    case .up:
        orientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation.up
    case .down:
        orientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation.down
    case .left:
        orientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation.left
    case .right:
        orientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation.right
    case .upMirrored:
        orientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation.upMirrored
    case .downMirrored:
        orientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation.downMirrored
    case .leftMirrored:
        orientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation.leftMirrored
    case .rightMirrored:
        orientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation.rightMirrored
    }
    
    let referenceImage = ARReferenceImage(marker.cgImage!, orientation: orientation, physicalWidth: 0.15)
    
    configuration.detectionImages = [mareferenceImageker]
    configuration.environmentTexturing = .none
    configuration.isLightEstimationEnabled = true
    
    _arSession.run(configuration, options:  [.removeExistingAnchors, .resetTracking])
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am under a bit of a time crunch to get this version out but before I was looking for just this so I get make the app size more efficient. The bundles of reference images would be like 70+ images each so I will definitely implement this so it doesn't start struggling.

Comment: @tobasco7454 Don't forget to accept or upvote my answer if it helped or will help you in the future :)